# Navigation from frame 1 to frame 2 renders event listeners non-functional in flash/actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, event-listener

I am new to actionscript and flash, and I have been unable to find a good explanation for why I cannot get this pretty basic code to work.  I am using flash cc with actionscript 3.  I have two frames on my timeline, one labeled "startFrame" and another labeled "newFrame".  In "startFrame", I have a button with the instance name "btnStart".  There is an event listener that listens for a mouse click on btnStart and then calls a function that goes to the next frame.  Here is the code for "startFrame":

```
stop();

//When "btnStart" button is clicked, call the beginSession function.
btnStart.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, beginSession);

function beginSession(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    //Remove event listener??
    //btnStart.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, beginSession);

    //Go to newFrame.
    gotoAndStop("newFrame");
}
```

I thought initially I should remove the event listener in the function after it is called, but it doesn't seem to work whether I remove the event listener or not.  Here I have it commented out.  In the "newFrame" frame, I have an event listener that listens for a key press and then calls a function that returns the key and character codes for that given key.  That code is here:

```
stop();

//show that newFrame has been reached.
trace("newFrame has been reached");

//Add event listener for a key press to the stage.
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, reportKeyDown);

//function that returns the key pressed and the character code.
function reportKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void 
{ 
    trace("Key Pressed: " + String.fromCharCode(event.charCode) + " (character code: " + event.keyCode + ")"); 
}
```

When I test the movie, the button press works and "newFrame" is reached (the "newFrame has been reached" trace is found in the output).  But it does not seem that the event listener for the key press is working.  However, if I create a project that only has "newFrame" by itself (no other frames in the timeline), it works just fine when I test the movie.  Only after I add in the startFrame and the button navigation do the event listeners seem to no longer hear the key press event in the second frame.  Also, I am not getting any compile errors.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Check if your project is compiling in DEBUG mode. If not, select the debug mode, otherwise the thing that doesn't work is the trace, not the listener.

Comment: Still doesn't work in debug mode.  The trace seems to be working well, however.  I am getting a trace back.  I still suspect it is the listener.  I added the following line to frame 2:  stage.focus = stage;  This seemed to do the trick.  The code is now functional.  I only hope that this fix does not somehow complicate things for me down the road as I continue on with this project.

Comment: The fix shouldn't make things complicated, because `focus` is not the thing that should be set in stone. It changes, but as far as the focus is within the current frame (or current stage), the stage will receive keyboard events and trigger the listener. Apparently changing frame does something with focus scope which I am not aware of, because I don't program in Flash CS, only in FlashDevelop, thus I don't have access to timeline, and this rendered the event flow to go some other way.

Answer (score 0):

Disable keyboard shortcuts under view while testing the application.

Comment: I am using flash professional cc, which does not seem to have this option under view.  I have found that this is highly recommended, but it seems that this option either a) does not exist in flash professional cc, or b) it is found somewhere I am not looking.